# "vdpau-va-driver" has unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04, any official resolution?

Tags: 16.04, video, gpu-driver, kodi

Kodi 18.1 on almost all the TV channels lags. It wasn't lagging a year ago, when I checked on a given machine (default 16.04 install and it doesn't counts what quality does the video have, nothing else is running in the background).

Maybe I can see some vdpau-va-driver related issues:

```
user@asdf:~$ kodi
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@asdf:~$
```

on package level:

```
root@asdf:~# apt-get install va-driver-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 va-driver-all : Depends: vdpau-va-driver but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# apt-get install vdpau-va-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vdpau-va-driver : Depends: libva-driver-abi-0.39 or
                            libva-driver-abi-0.31 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# 
root@asdf:~# grep ^[a-z] /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list:deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial main #Intel Graphics drivers
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/team-xbmc-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
root@asdf:~#
```

**The question**: how to resolve this dependency issue officially?

Already tried to use video driver updater via 01.org, but it stops because of the dependency issue. Dependency issue was there before the 01.org try too!

Google doesn't brings up any solution. Let's have one!

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update` (ensure that you do not have any error output here), and add output of `apt-cache policy va-driver-all mesa-va-drivers` to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same dependency conflict and investigated this a bit using the following commands

- checking package dependencies

  - [debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/va-driver-all) -> [ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/va-driver-all) -> [xbmc](https://launchpad.net/~sv-berger/+archive/ubuntu/kodi-org) (current policy)
  - use `apt-cache depends va-driver-all` (depends on)
  - use `apt-cache rdepends va-driver-all` (is dependency of)
- show package installed

  - use `apt-cache show libva1`

**Note:** For the short version scroll to the bottom of this entry.
The following passage is created so that it may serve as a reference for how to use apt-cache apt-get to resolve dependency conflicts. This is by no means a complete guide and it was my first investigation of apt conflicts, so if I misused or missed something please leave a comment, I am happy to learn!

**INVESTIGATION:**
What was confusing to me was that in the reference [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/va-driver-all) (for debian) the dependency is either `mesa-va-driver` or `vdpau-va-driver`. Since I am using ubuntu and requiring the ubuntu version of this package, I need the repository [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/va-driver-all) (ubuntu). Somehow in the development process to ubuntu the dependency is only on the `vdpau-va-driver`. I have however already installed the `mesa-va-driver`, which apparently breaks `vdpau-va-driver`, if I interpret the subsequent `apt-cache depends mesa-va-drivers` output correctly.

Edit: Stumbled across a great resource from the archlinux wiki that summarises the video acceleration libraries neatly. [see here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration)

```
~ $ sudo apt-cache depends mesa-va-drivers
mesa-va-drivers
  Depends: libva1
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1
  Depends: libdrm-nouveau2
  Depends: libdrm-radeon1
  Depends: libdrm2
  Depends: libelf1
  Depends: libexpat1
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libllvm6.0
  Depends: libsensors4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libx11-xcb1
  Depends: libxcb-dri2-0
  Depends: libxcb-dri3-0
  Depends: libxcb-present0
  Depends: libxcb-sync1
  Depends: libxcb-xfixes0
  Depends: libxcb1
  Depends: libxshmfence1
  Depends: zlib1g
  Breaks: vdpau-va-driver
  Replaces: vdpau-va-driver
  Enhances: libva1
```

The actual linked repository and its dependencies then can be seen using `apt-cache policy vdpau-va-driver` and is linked to the original ubuntu archive

```
sudo apt-cache depends vdpau-va-driver
vdpau-va-driver
  Depends: libc6
 |Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx
  Depends: <libgl1>
    libgl1-mesa-glx
  Depends: libvdpau1
  Depends: libx11-6
 |Depends: <libva-driver-abi-0.39>
  Depends: <libva-driver-abi-0.31>
  Enhances: libva1
~ $ sudo apt-cache policy vdpau-va-driver
vdpau-va-driver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.4-5
  Version table:
     0.7.4-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Where the installation of `vdpau-va-driver` with `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemSolver=yes install vdpau-va-driver`

```
~ $ sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemSolver=yes install vdpau-va-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vdpau-va-driver : Depends: libva-driver-abi-0.39 or
                            libva-driver-abi-0.31 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

fails due to the missing `libva-driver-abi-0.39.`

**Note:** Here is `libva-driver-abi-0.39` a virtual package of `libva1` which I already have installed. The corresponding `apt-cache policy libva1` output

```
~ $ apt-cache policy libva1
libva1:
  Installed: 1.7.3~xenial
  Candidate: 1.7.3~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.3~xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.7.0-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

shows that I have installed libva1 for kodi using the manually to my apt source list added repository `http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main`. [see](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

So the available version `vdpau-va-driver` is linked to the archive ubuntu version of `libva1`, which is 1.7.0-1 while the kodi repository from `team-xbmc` has already version 1.7.3 from which it seems that the link of the `vdpau-va-driver` to the ubuntu archive version requires either the virtual package `libva-driver-abi-0.31` or `libva-driver-abi-0.39` from `libva1` but the **team-xbmc** version seems not to provide it, or atleast my apt package manager can't find it.

In conclusion the policy output shows  the following chain

mesa-va-drivers (ubuntu)

libva1 (**xbmc**) -> va-driver-all (**xbmc**) -> vdpau-va-driver (**ubuntu**) -> libva-driver-abi-0.31 or - 0.39 (**ubuntu**) -> libva1 (**ubuntu**) -x-> libva1 installed (**xbmc**)

```
~ $ apt-cache policy mesa-va-drivers vdpau-va-driver va-driver-all libva1
mesa-va-drivers:
  Installed: 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Candidate: 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
vdpau-va-driver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.4-5
  Version table:
     0.7.4-5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
va-driver-all:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.3~xenial
  Version table:
     1.7.3~xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
libva1:
  Installed: 1.7.3~xenial
  Candidate: 1.7.3~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.3~xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.7.0-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

I suspect that the xbmc repository `http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main` causes some dependency conflicts or is missing the virtual package, but could also be the package manager and some misconfiguration locally.

**DETERMINE DEPENDENCIES:**
However with the following output of `apt-cache rdepends va-driver-all` the problem causing package can be investigated about what it actually affects on your system

```
~ $ apt-cache rdepends va-driver-all
va-driver-all
Reverse Depends:
 |libva1
 |libva1
 |libva1
~ $ apt-cache depends libva1
libva1
  Depends: libc6
  Breaks: vlc-nox
 |Recommends: va-driver-all
  Recommends: <va-driver>
    i965-va-driver
    mesa-va-drivers
    vdpau-va-driver
```

**PACKAGE REMOVAL:**
Here it shows that only `libva1` wants this package `va-driver-all` but only as a recommend, meaning it should not break something or still work without it. Therefore removing the package is done using

`sudo apt-get remove va-driver-all`

**TL/DR**: The conclusion is to investigate the dependency and if nothing depends on the problem causing package removing it. See the last two command listings for how to investigate whether to remove it.