# Error upgrading Xubuntu 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, xubuntu, lts, do-release-upgrade

Following the procedure:

1. Upgrade all installed packages of Ubuntu version 18.04 by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` command.
2. Reboot the Ubuntu Linux system by tying the `sudo reboot command`
3. Install the Ubuntu update tool, run: `sudo apt install update-manager-core`
4. Start the upgrade procedure, run: `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Here I get stuck and this is the output:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

But I completed the previous steps with no errors.

How can I upgrade my Xubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04? It seems that some packages are impossible to upgrade and this may cause the upgrade to fail. I will investigate deeply. In the meanwhile, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can't directly upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04. You can upgrade to 18.04. Try to run `do-release-upgrade` without `sudo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "sudo: unable to resolve host (none)"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)

Comment: trying and updating the question asap!

Comment: @Pilot6. without `sudo` same output

Comment: @Pilot6, how to pass from 16.04 to 18.04? Suggestion?

Comment: You need to fix sudo first. I gave a link.

Comment: doing right now!

Comment: @Pilot6, `sudo` fixed with `echo $(hostname -I | cut -d\  -f1) $(hostname) | sudo -h 127.0.0.1 tee -a /etc/hosts`. Rebooting, and the problem is still there!

Comment: `sudo apt full-upgrade` is usually used to fully upgrade a system (it won't *bump* you to the next release unless you've wrongly *hacked* your sources). `apt upgrade` can in certain circumstances leave some upgrades behind (why the full-upgrade command exists).  If you have issues and have tried `sudo apt full-upgrade` (or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) your issue could be your sources (ie. read `sudo apt update` & it's messages looking for missing lines)

Comment: @guiverc yes, this was exactly the problem. I just completely removed the package that was causing the problem and now the upgrade of Xubuntu is going on. The packages were (1) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132184/vdpau-va-driver-has-unmet-dependencies-on-ubuntu-16-04-any-official-resolutio and (2) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167967/apt-get-update-issue-with-pinta-repository . I will write an answer to this question as soon as the whole upgrade is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

After an investigation, it seems that there were two packages causing the problems: Pinta and some other unknown packages of Kodi. Simply, the system is not able to upgrade them or the repositories are not reachable. The two useful links I have read are [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132184/vdpau-va-driver-has-unmet-dependencies-on-ubuntu-16-04-any-official-resolutio) and [this other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167967/apt-get-update-issue-with-pinta-repository). It is true that I did not think that these packages were crucial for the system to complete the process. Howerever they were.

So I simply uninstall them with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge <package_name>` and the process `sudo do-release-upgrade` continues with no problems anymore.

> General Solution: if you have similar errors/problems, try to solve all the update/upgrade one by one before the `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

In my case, it automatically and autonomously passed from `16.04` to `18.04` and, then, from `18.04` to `20.04`.